# como puedo liberar el puerto 8080

Tags: java, glassfish, puertos

necesito trabajar con el servidor glassfish de java y este requiere el puerto 8080 cosa que no puedo hacer por que se encuentra ya siendo escuchado y no puedo saber por quien  me aparece "No se puede obtener información de propiedad" netstat -b -a -n puede alguien explicarme por favor como hago para desabilitar  ese puerto o que otro puerto puedo usar para ese servidor.

Answer (score 0):

`netstat -b -a -n` te debería de funcionar para saber cuál programa esta utilizando el puerto, pero tienes que ejecutar el símbolo de sistema en en MODO ADMINISTRADOR para que funcione.

Answer (score 0):

Dos formas, o busca la aplicación que esta usando el puerto 8080 (como menciona Rne) y la bajas o cambia la configuración de glasfish y cambia el puerto de escucha `HTTP_LISTENER_PORT` por un puerto que este disponible, en el ejemplo el `28080`

El archivo de configuración se encuentra en `/carpeta_instalación/glassfish/domains/domain1/config` y el archivo es el `domain.xml`

```
<system-property name="JMS_PROVIDER_PORT" value="27676" description="Port Number that JMS Service will listen for remote clients connection." />
<system-property name="ASADMIN_LISTENER_PORT" value="24848"/>
<system-property name="HTTP_LISTENER_PORT" value="28080"/>
<system-property name="HTTP_SSL_LISTENER_PORT" value="28181"/>
<system-property name="IIOP_LISTENER_PORT" value="23700"/>
<system-property name="IIOP_SSL_LISTENER_PORT" value="23820"/>
<system-property name="IIOP_SSL_MUTUALAUTH_PORT" value="23920"/>
<system-property name="JMX_SYSTEM_CONNECTOR_PORT" value="28686"/>
<system-property name="OSGI_SHELL_TELNET_PORT" value="26666"/>
<system-property name="JAVA_DEBUGGER_PORT" value="29009"/>
```